# Show link only to user with permission to edit

Tags: nodes

I'm using the following code to show the *Edit* button to edit pages in my blog teasers and others content types.

```
<a href="<?php echo '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
```

It works fine, but it shows for all users, even the users with no permission to edit. How can I hide it for users that don't have permission to edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking of the *blog* content type, you should need to use code that checks:

- If the user who is currently viewing the blog node is the author of the node and has the "edit own blog content" permission
- If the user who is currently viewing the blog node is not the author of the node and has the "edit any blog content" permission

  ```
  <?php
    if ('[node:author:nid]' == $GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
      $permission = user_access('edit own blog content');
    }
    else {
      $permission = user_access('edit any blog content');
    } 
  ?>
  <?php if ($permission): ?>
    <a href="<?php print '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

A more generic code would be the following one.

```
<?php $item = menu_get_item('[node:edit-url]'); ?>
<?php if (!empty($item['access'])): ?>
  <a href="<?php print '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code is more generic because it shows the link whenever the current user has access to the edit link, whatever permissions are required to see that link. It could be a module alters which users can see the node edit page, and this code would take that in consideration.
The code is assuming [node:edit-url] is a URL like node/10/edit; if the URL is /node/10/edit or http://example.com/node/10/edit, then the code needs to be changed to extract the node/10/edit part, since that is the string [menu_get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) is expecting. See for example the code used by [blog_menu_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!blog!blog.module/function/blog_menu_local_tasks_alter/7).

```
  // Add action link to 'node/add/blog' on 'blog' page.
  if ($root_path == 'blog') {
    $item = menu_get_item('node/add/blog');
    if ($item['access']) {
      $item['title'] = t('Create new blog entry');
      $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
        '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
        '#link' => $item,
      );
    }
  }
```

That code is part of the Blog module, and it uses `menu_get_item()` to check if the currently logged-in user has access to the page to create a new blog. It doesn't merely verify the user has the permission to create a blog node, since that would not be enough if a module changes when a user can access the node create form.
Also note that the argument passed to `menu_get_item()` doesn't have a / at the beginning.

Notice that the Token module defines a URL token type, for which it makes available the following sub-tokens:

- path, the path component of the URL
- relative, the relative URL
- absolute, the absolute URL
- brief, the URL without the protocol and trailing backslash
- unaliased, the unaliased URL
- arg, the specific argument of the current page (e.g. 'arg:1' on the page 'node/1' returns '1')

Unfortunately, at the moment the type for node:edit-url is not set to url; when it is, the following code will work.

```
<?php $item = menu_get_item('[node:edit-url:path]'); ?>
<?php if (!empty($item['access'])): ?>
  <a href="<?php print '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the node_access function to see whether the current user can perform operations on a given node:

```
<?php if (node_access('update', $node)): ?>
  <!-- edit link here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access

Answer (score 1):

Use [user_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) function. Pass target permission as parameter. For node edit access you can use `'administer nodes'`.

```
<?php if(user_access('administer nodes')): ?>
  <a href="<?php print '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update**

You can work with permission for editing own content. Permissions are set in drupal per each content type. For example for `article` content type permission will be `edit own article content`.

```
<?php if(user_access('edit any article content')): ?>
   <a href="<?php print '[node:edit-url]';?>">Edit</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hello milkovsky, now it's only showing to administrator. I'm trying to make this visible also to authenticated user with permission to edit  their own content. Do you know how can I do this? Thank you a lot

Comment: I updated the answer. But kiamlaluno's answer describes solution better